# Google Oauth2 without redirect

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Hei guys,

I have a little test on an interview, but im so confused.

Page 1: Login with Google OAuth

UI fields: Email Address, Password, Login button

Show success/error notification after clicking login

Redirect to bucket list (see next step)

The only way that i saw i can log in with google is with a redirect to their ui:

[image]

How im supposed to make a google auth with value of email and password? and clicking login button to check if the user credentials are good.

Comment: If the task was to integrate with Google Authentication, then you probably don't have to worry about there not being a username or password field. They will appear if you are logged out of google though!

Comment: i see, thank you ^^